# How to get 100% ADA compliance result in accessibility checker website https://webaccessibility.com?

Tags: javascript, php, html, accessibility

I am trying to make a PHP website ADA(Americans with Disability Act) Compliant. My client wants to get 100% output result when we check website on the accessibility checker website https://webaccessibility.com . But I am getting result 89%. There is only one error which I am unable to solve. I even tried testing a simple HTML code as following:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>homepage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it still shows same error as following:

Developers should define the natural language of a document to ensure that screen readers and other user agents understand the language the document is to be interpreted in.  Specifically, when a document contains multiple inline language choices, screen readers and other assistive technology types must know what the default language type is to ensure they can appropriately switch between languages. 
Per the HTML 4.01 recommendation, language declarations should be made in accordance with IETF RFC 1766.

- Always declare the default language for text in the page using
  attributes on the html tag.
- Do NOT use the meta element with the content attribute set to
  Content-Language.
- Use language attributes rather than HTTP to declare the default
  language for 'text processing' (ie. when language needs to be known
  for things such as font choice, styling, spell-checking,
  hyphentation, quote mark styling, etc.).
- Do not declare the default language of a document in the body
  element, use the html element.
- Where a document contains content aimed at speakers of more than one
  language, decide whether you want to declare one language in the html
  tag, or leave the languages undefined until later.
- Where a document contains content aimed at speakers of more than one
  language, try to divide the document linguistically at the highest
  possible level, and declare the appropriate language for each of
  those divisions.
- For HTML use the lang attribute only, for XHTML 1.0 served as
  text/html use the lang and xml:lang attributes, and for XHTML served
  as XML use the xml:lang attribute only.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the natural language of a document with with the `lang` attribute:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>homepage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

This probably won't get you to 100% compliance - and we can't possibly be expected to do that for you here - but the error you reference in your post refers to the missing language definition.

Comment: well said.  companies pay big bucks to get their sites accessible.  providing that service for free on stackoverflow is not an option, but specific issues can certainly be asked about, as in this case where it lacked the `lang` attribute.